# str_replace wrong decimal

Tags: php

this is my first question here at Stackoverflow so please bear with me :)

What I have been trying to do for the last couple of hours is replacing symbols on upload and download from the database.

```
How it should be:
Input: 100.000,25
Stored in database: 100000.25
Output: 100.200,25
```

The reason hereof is that i need the comma as decimal separator, and dot as thousand separators. I need to still be able to add/multiply and more with the numbers stored in the database.

What works the best of what I have tried so far:

```
// Value from form input:
$value = 100.200,25;

// Removing all but numbers and comma


$remove_symbols = array("+"," ",".","-","'","\"","&","!","?",":",";","#","~","=","/","$","£","^","(",")","_","<",">");
$db_value = str_replace($remove_symbols, '', $value);



      // $db_value  insert into db

        // Pulling out the data
        $db_pulled = number_format($row['liter'],2,',','.');  
        echo $db_pulled;

   :( returns: 100.200,00 (should return 100.200,25)
```

Comment: oh sweet chewbacca. stop using a blacklist. use a white list of 0-9 and .  better yet, use pure number formatting

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are a bit confusing and you don't tag them well. For example a **php** tag would be more appropriate and sufficient. (I've modified it for you now)

OK. The problem you are having is because you need to replace comma with a dot because that's how float values are represented. In your example it probably gets truncated when you insert it in the DB.

here is what you can do:

```
<?php
        $numString = "100.200,25";
        $numString = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('','.'), $numString);
        $num = floatval($numString);
        echo $num;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your code returns: 100.200,00 (should return 100.200,25)

Your databases table field seems to be in Int format instead of Decimal format.

For more information about Numeric field types visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html